# Login page for .NET MAUI

Tags: .net, shell, authentication, maui

I have a simple .NET MAUI application and am trying to implement a login page. The goal is nothing more than to show the login page and when the user submits name and password it will go to a view model that will then pass the user along to MainPage. This works, but when it gets to MainPage there are no tabs. My Appshell.xaml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

```
<ShellItem>
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:Login}" />
</ShellItem>


<TabBar >
    <ShellContent
        Title="Home"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
        Icon="icon_home" />

    <ShellContent
        Title="About"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:About}"
        Icon="icon_about" />

   </TabBar>
```

Is there an obvious solution to this issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is one way to solve this:

- Remove "Login" from Shell xaml.
- In `App.xaml.cs`, there is a line `MainPage = new AppShell();`. Replace this with `MainPage = new Login();`.
- When login succeeds, do `Application.Current.MainPage = new AppShell();` - the line that was originally in App.xaml.cs.

NOTE: I am NOT recommending *frequently* calling "new AppShell()". But for Login, it is fine to delay that call until after Login succeeds.

See also [H.A.H.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74291417/199364), which shows an alternative approach, that does not involve directly changing `MainPage`. I have not tested that answer myself.

Comment: That's a good approach. Do you have any idea about how to skip the login page if a user is already signed in when re-opens the app?

Comment: Yes. In Login Page's OnAppearing, check if they are logged in. If so, do the navigation to AppShell. OnAppearing happens just before the page appears, so that will prevent its appearance.

Comment: Sorry if asking too much, I'm kinda stuck in this step, I look everywhere but couldn't find much. How to save the logged-in information after the app is restarted by the user?

Comment: google `.net maui save login info site:stackoverflow.com`

Comment: it might be needed MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Login()); if there are links on Login to navigate like 'forgotpassword'.

Comment: @TiagoT it might be needed more than that. Those constructors may take other objects as parameters. And before you call this constructor, they need to be constructed as well. Then their constructors may take other objects as parameters, and you have to manually construct them too. And you have to manage the life cycle of those objects. Manually. This is why people use Dependency Injection. I understand if this was happening years ago, and it would take you time to implement it, but MAUI has built-in DI. All you have to do is use it. You are advising people basically not to use it.

Comment: i took what i said after reading from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/navigationpage?view=net-maui-7.0

Comment: @H.A.H. - The pre-supplied Maui code being altered in this answer is `MainPage = new AppShell();`. **This already isn't DI.** Therefore, `MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Login());` seems to be one logical modification of the existing code. If you have a suggestion as to how to alter `MainPage = new NavigationPage...` to use DI, I'd love to hear it. I'd be happy to promote a clean way to set Maui's initial MainPage, for those who choose to use `NavigationPage`, which is one of Maui's "built-in" navigation paradigms, co-equal to AppShell.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve My suggestion, to you, and to everyone else, is to never use constructors for navigation.

Comment: I am well aware that that is your view. HOWEVER, that doesn't answer my question, which is how to REPLACE .Net Maui's **hardcoded** use of `new AppShell();`, **which is a constructor**, with the equally valid Maui Navigation paradigm of `NavigationPage`. Maui itself already violates your viewpoint; it uses a constructor to initialize the navigation. Do you know any way to avoid this? Or alternatively, do you have any suggestion how to inject a page (`Login`) into `NavigationPage`, so it could be reduced to `MainPage = new NavigationPage();` -- no worse than `MainPage = new AppShell();`

Answer (score 4):

Inside the TabBar, I use Tab and inside it - ShellContent.

```
<TabBar>
        <Tab Title="..."
             Route="HomePage"
             Icon="...">
            <ShellContent
                Title="..."
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:HomePage}" />
        </Tab>
</TabBar>
```

Navigation after login happens with:

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(HomePage)}");
```

No change of Application main page is required. Navigation between your Shell components works perfectly fine. Avoid using the word "new" as much as you can.
The two slashes clear the stack, so the user cannot navigate back to the login page, without using sign out button.

(Think for a second, if you need to pass data from login page, eula page, or something else to the main page, how you will do it. And then tell me if it is smart to construct your AppShell...)

Comment: Answer is not complete (I upvoted it anyway, its a useful start). This does not show how to declare a LoginPage, and make it appear when app starts up, then not be seen again. DETAILS: The user should not be able to  click anywhere and return to it (its only visible while logging in), so it should not be declared in the TabBar. OR, if it is part of TabBar, this answer should show how to "hide" it, once user has logged in. OR if the intention is to have it be a "Logout" page (when user has logged in), then this answer should show how to transform its Tab Name and Contents based on Login state.

Comment: The target of this question is that he is trying to navigate to his main page, and it is empty. (It works as expected, the way he is declaring his shell contents, and navigating to them). I showed him the right way to make sure he gets to MainPage and there are tabs there.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough reputation to comment therefore I can't join the thread on the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/users/199364/toolmakersteve so I'll post a new answer.

To avoid instantiating a login page directly in the App's constructor, you can inject an IServiceProvider into the the App's constructor and call GetService to have the DI container build your LoginPage like so.

```cs
    public App(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    
        var loginPage = serviceProvider.GetService();
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(loginPage);
    }
```

**Update:**

I've been playing around with a different approach which seems to be working for me, I've tested this on Windows and an Android emulator. I've created two app shells, a standard one for authenticated users and another for unauthenticated users. This allows for a navigation stack for login pages, forgot password pages etc with functioning back buttons, but once authenticated a new navigation stack is created with the new app shell.

My app shell for authenticated users is standard with the MainPage as it's root page. Here's my AppShell.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="NavigationTest.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NavigationTest"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled">

    <ShellContent
        Title="Home"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
        Route="MainPage" />

</Shell>
```

I've then created an UnauthenticatedAppShell where the LoginPage will be the root page for this shell, here's UnauthenticatedAppShell.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="NavigationTest.UnauthenticatedAppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:accountViews="clr-namespace:NavigationTest.Views.Account"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled">

    <ShellContent
        Title="Login"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate accountViews:LoginPage}"
        Route="LoginPage">

    </ShellContent>

</Shell>
```

and I've registered my ForgotPassword page in UnauthenticatedAppShell.cs

```cs
    public partial class UnauthenticatedAppShell : Shell
    {
        public UnauthenticatedAppShell()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Routing.RegisterRoute("ForgotPasswordPage", typeof(Views.Account.ForgotPasswordPage));
        }
    }
```

In App.cs I'm setting the MainPage to an instance of the UnauthenticatedAppShell

```cs
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainPage = new UnauthenticatedAppShell();
        }
    }
```

For both of my root pages for each app shell, MainPage and LoginPage,  I'm injecting in instances of the relevant view models and hooking up actions (Authentictaed in LoginViewModel and LoggedOut in MainViewModel) to swap over the relevant app shells, and actions (which I've called GoTo) to allow me to trigger navigation from view models to the app shell which means I don't need a dependency to the app shell in my view models.

LoginPage.cs

```cs
    public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
    {
        public LoginPage(LoginViewModel loginViewModel)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = loginViewModel;
            loginViewModel.GoTo = async route => await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(route);
            loginViewModel.Authenticated += () => Application.Current.MainPage = new AppShell();
        }
    }
```

MainPage.cs

```cs
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage(MainViewModel mainViewModel)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = mainViewModel;
            mainViewModel.GoTo = async route => await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(route);
            mainViewModel.LoggedOut += () => Application.Current.MainPage = new UnauthenticatedAppShell();
        }
    }
```

Comment: But how to proceed from there? Would it be like

`public partial class LoginPage: ContentPage
{
    public LoginPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.MainPage = new AppShell();
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(MainPage)}");
    }
}`

Comment: @Veksi I've updated my answer with an alternative, more complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've come with another solution. Just play with the `IsVisible` property in your shell.

```
<FlyoutItem Route="login"
            Title="Login"
            IsVisible="False">
    <Tab Route="domestic"
         Title="Domestiques">
        <ShellContent Route="cats" 
                      Title="cats"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:NewPage1}"/>
        <ShellContent Route="dogs" 
                      Title="dogs"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:NewPage2}"/>
    </Tab>
    <ShellContent Route="monkeys"
                  Title="monkeys"
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:FirstPage}" />
</FlyoutItem>
```

It will be hidden. Be aware that the ShellContent must be visible if you navigate to it with a url.

You can set a `BindingContext` to your AppShell and then bind the `IsVisible` property to some property of your view-model

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use the Route property of your TabBar and redirect it when authenticating example:

```
<ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:LoginPage}" />
<TabBar Route="LocationPage">
    <Tab Title="Home">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:LocationPage}"/>
    </Tab>

    <Tab Title="Perfil">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:LocationPage}"/>
    </Tab>
</TabBar>
```

In my ViewModel:

```
public partial class LoginViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    public string _userName = "";

    [ObservableProperty]
    public string _password = "";

    [RelayCommand]
    public async Task Login()
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(LocationPage)}");
    }
}
```

I hope this can help someone and I am open to corrections of this piece of code.