# How to navigate in Xamarin Shell app with login and splashscreen flow

Tags: c#, xamarin, navigation

I've the requirement to create a login flow described by the following image:
[image]

I've just created a Xamarin app with all the required pages as described in the image and I am using the AppShell in order to navigate among them.
I've an issue when clicking the "logout" button because instead of showing the "welcome page" it is returning to the "login page".

I paste here the code that I have inside each page:

- Splashscreen page:

  - If already loggen in: `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(HomePage)}");`
  - If not logged in: `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(WelcomePage)}");`
- Welcome page:

  - If login button clicked: `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(LoginPage)}");`
  - If signup button clicked: `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(SignUpPage)}");`
- Home page (**from the account tab page**):

  - If logout button clicked: `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(WelcomePage)}");`
- Registration page:

  - If user signed up: `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(WelcomePage)}/{nameof(LoginPage)}");`
- Login page:

  - If login button clicked: `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(HomePage)}");`

Furthermore, I've the following code in my AppShell.xaml:

```
...
<ShellItem Route="LoadingPage">
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoadingPage}" />
</ShellItem>
<ShellContent Route="WelcomePage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:WelcomePage}"/>
<TabBar>
<ShellContent Title="Home" Route="HomePage" Icon="icon_home.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:HomePage}" />
    <ShellContent Title="Items" Route="ItemsPage" Icon="icon_items.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ItemsPage}" />
    <ShellContent Title="Account" Route="AccountPage" Icon="icon_account.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AccountPage}" />
</TabBar>
```

And the following is inside the AppShell.cs:

```
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(LoginPage), typeof(LoginPage));
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(SignUpPage), typeof(SignUpPage));
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(ItemDetailPage), typeof(ItemDetailPage));
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(NewItemPage), typeof(NewItemPage));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Login page for .NET MAUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74269299/login-page-for-net-maui)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command to navigate. Here is the demo code in MainPage.xaml:

```
<Button   Text="Button" 
          Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}"
          CommandParameter="{x:Type views:CustomizeEntryPage}" />
```

Here is the code in MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
 public ICommand NavigateCommand { get; private set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        NavigateCommand = new Command<Type>(
            async (Type pageType) =>
            {
                Page page = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(pageType);
                await Navigation.PushAsync(page);
            });

        BindingContext = this;
    }
```