# Flyout Page not responding

Tags: maui

I'm starting understanding .Net MAUI with an online video.
I'm trying to customize a page with 3 buttons, 1 for a counter, 1 for a second page and 1 for a flyoutpage.
Counter and second page are ok, flyout page doesn't display but force the App to exit.
My code for the button that calls the flyout page is this, located in the MainPage.xml.cs :

```
private void FlyClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Navigation.PushAsync(new Flyout1());
}
```

Can anybody explain me the reason of this ?
Many Thanks

Comment: *"flyout page doesn't display but force the App to exit"* Perhaps a problem with `Flyout1`s contents.  Inside Flyout1's constructor, I would put `try .. catch (Exception ex)` around all its lines of codes. Then a breakpoint in the `catch` block. Does it get to breakpoint? If so, add to question the full text of the Exception. Another test is to make a blank Flyout. No contents; as simple as possible. Does going to that also crash?

Comment: Thanks ToolmakerSteve for this answer. My Flyout page is completely blank, but i don't know where to put the Try Catch structure...maybe in this way?

Comment: And If I check your App.xaml.cs, I wont find there: MainPage = new AppShell();? I will place my money on trying to use Navigation pages and Shell at the same time. If this is the case... you cant.

Comment: "And If I check your App.xaml.cs, I wont find there: MainPage = new AppShell();?"
Yes, there is that line.....

Comment: @Livio Well, here is your answer. Mixing those 2 navigation types is not possible. Either shell, or navigation page. Strongly recommend shell. good luck.

Comment: @H.A.H. Thanks also to you. :-) But if I want to display this flyout page starting from a main page with a button like my intention? Can you show me a bit of code? :-)

Comment: @Livio I can but I wont. I use Shell and DI. The amount of work and problems this approach is saving me on daily basis, is worth more to me than all the Flyout pages in the world. However, ToolmakerSteve has answer, that will allow you to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74279871/6643940.

Comment: @H.A.H. Same problem with a TabbedPage....also this type of page is impossible to launch with the Navigation.PushAsync command?

Comment: @Livio Shell navigation is done, with Shell.Current.GoToAsync(...). This way you are using routes, not too different than your navigation in any web site. Pages are using stack. Imagine a deck of cards, where you place a card on top of all others, and it gets displayed. Navigation.Push method puts a page in the stack. Pop - removes it. Tabbed, Flyout - does not matter. The concept of the stack navigation is not compatible with Shell navigation. You have URI navigation there.

Comment: To clarify: `Navigation.PushASync` is a `NavigationPage` command. That requires App's MainPage to be `NavigationPage`. Maui by default uses `Shell`, thus `Shell.GoToAsync`, as HAH says. Search `maui shell navigation` for doc. (My answer, that HAH linked, shows how to start with NavigationPage instead. Don't do this, unless you have a good reason. Its best to start with shell  navigation doc.)

Comment: Great!!! Many, many thanks for all these suggestions!!!!!! You are wonderful!!! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, the `Flyout1` should be a [FlyoutPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/flyoutpage?view=net-maui-7.0). You can refer to the code below on how to create a `FlyoutPage`. I test it and it can display it.

### **Flyout1:**

**XAML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<FlyoutPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiAppDualScreen.Flyout1"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiAppDualScreen"
             >

    <FlyoutPage.Flyout>
        <local:FlyoutMenuPage x:Name="flyoutPage" />
    </FlyoutPage.Flyout>
    <FlyoutPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage>
            <x:Arguments>
                <local:MainPage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </FlyoutPage.Detail>
</FlyoutPage>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
public partial class Flyout1 : FlyoutPage
{
      public Flyout1()
      {
            InitializeComponent();
      }
}
```

The following example shows the definition of the `FlyoutMenuPage` object, which is of type `ContentPage`:

**XAML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiAppDualScreen.FlyoutMenuPage"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiAppDualScreen"
             Title="FlyoutMenuPage">
    <CollectionView x:Name="collectionView"
                    x:FieldModifier="public"
                    SelectionMode="Single">
        <CollectionView.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type local:FlyoutPageItem}">
                <local:FlyoutPageItem Title="Contacts"
                                      IconSource="dotnet_bot.png"
                                      TargetType="{x:Type local:MainPage}" />
                <local:FlyoutPageItem Title="TodoList"
                                      IconSource="dotnet_bot.png"
                                      TargetType="{x:Type local:MainPage}" />
                <local:FlyoutPageItem Title="Reminders"
                                      IconSource="dotnet_bot.png"
                                      TargetType="{x:Type local:MainPage}" />
            </x:Array>
        </CollectionView.ItemsSource>
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Padding="5,10">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Source="{Binding IconSource}" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="1"
                           Margin="20,0"
                           Text="{Binding Title}"
                           FontSize="20"
                           FontAttributes="Bold"
                           VerticalOptions="Center" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</ContentPage>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
public partial class FlyoutMenuPage : ContentPage
{
      public FlyoutMenuPage()
      {
            InitializeComponent();
      }
}
```

The flyout page consists of a `CollectionView` that's populated with data by setting its `ItemsSource` property to an array of `FlyoutPageItem` objects. The following example shows the definition of the `FlyoutPageItem` class:

```
public class FlyoutPageItem
{
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string IconSource { get; set; }
        public Type TargetType { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: sorry, i noticed only now your question. Yes, your code works, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: sorry but i'm new here in Stackoverflow so i don't know how to accept...can you explain me? Thanks!