# How can I implement logout in a .NET MAUI application that uses shell and tabs?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, mobile, maui

How can I gracefully allow the user to logout and send him to the login screen again in a .NET MAUI Shell Application?

This is my AppShell.xaml:

```
<Shell
x:Class="Xen.Presentation.Mobile.AppShell"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Xen.Presentation.Mobile"
xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Xen.Presentation.Mobile.Views"
Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled">

<ShellContent Title="LogIn" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:LogInPage}" />

<TabBar Route="Main">
    <Tab Title="Inicio" Icon="home.png">
        <ShellContent Title="Home" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:HomePage}" />
    </Tab>
    
    <!-- Other tabs -->
    
    <Tab Title="Perfil" Icon="user.png">
        <ShellContent Title="Perfil" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:UserPage}" />
    </Tab>
</TabBar>

<ShellContent Title="Professional" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:ProfessionalPage}" />

<!-- Other pages -->

</Shell>
```

This is the login page when the user first opens the app:

[image]

On the LoginViewModel I have a SignInCommand that after authentication sends the user to the  main TabBar:

```
    private async void OnSignInCommand()
    {
        // Authentication and validations
        
        // Go to the home page
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//Main");
        
    }
```

I have on my UserViewModel a button where the user should be able to logout. This is the code the LogoutCommand calls:

```
    private async Task OnLogout()
    {
        App.LoggedInUser = null;
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(LogInPage));
    }
```

This is the Login screen after I clear the user information and redirect to the login page. As you can see on the bottom of the page the tabs are still visible despite the fact that the LogInPage is registered outside of the TabBar in the Shell.xaml.

How can I implement this in a way that the user goes back to the login without the tabs being visible at the bottom?

[image]

Comment: When you logout, set the MainPage to LoginPage.  After successful login, set it to your AppShell

Comment: Short answer - do "//" when navigating to login page. For more information how and why, you can check my full answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Login page for .NET MAUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74269299/login-page-for-net-maui)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First in your Shell XAML you need this:

```
<ShellItem Route="LoginPage">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:LoginPage}"/>
</ShellItem>
```

And then all you have to do is call:

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(LoginPage)}");
```

(Usually after clearing your access token)

Routed Shell items do not require registration. And allow you to navigate to them with "//". This clears the stack - very useful, because you do not want people to be able to go back, without going through login process.

Edit2:
Remove random lines you have like:

```
<ShellContent Title="LogIn" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:LogInPage}" />
```

Or:

```
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(LogInPage), typeof(LogInPage));
```

And do just this:

```
<ShellItem Route="LogInPage">
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:LogInPage}"/>
</ShellItem>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but when I call GoToAsync() in the way you have specified I get this error: "'Global routes currently cannot be the only page on the stack, so absolute routing to global routes is not supported. For now, just navigate to: LogInPage'"

Comment: @adamasan show me your Shell xaml.

Comment: @adamasan have you even edited it? Read what I write to you, and implement the changes exactly the same way. I will stress on this again: routed shell items are allowed to be navigated to with "//". Define your shell item, specify the route (the same as your page name), and set it as Shell Content.  The code I am giving you is from working project.

Comment: I've changed the code. But I forgot that I had the same registration in the code behind. I removed it and now your code worked just fine. Thank you very much!

Comment: The last app I build was with Xamarin a long time ago, I clearly went over my head with Shell. It has a bit more complexity that the old ways with NavigationPage. Will take some time to study the routing before my application gets any larger.

Comment: @adamasan If you ask me, you made the right choice.